# advance custom field: missing value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Here is my problem:

I created a field named « subtitle » which is supposed to appear on an overlay, on the portfolio thumbnails of my theme.

I inserted the code like that:

```
$gallery .= '<h2 class="portfolio-title">' . $title . '</h2>';
$gallery .= '<h3 class="portfolio-subtitle">' .the_field('subtitle') .'</h3>';                              
$gallery .= '<span>' . ut_generate_cat_list( $portfolio_cats ) . '</span>’;
```

In the front-end, I see through Firebug that the field is there, but no value appears in it!

What do I need to get the value ?
Do I need to insert a function in my function.php file ?
Or maybe my code is not correct ?

Thanks in advance for helping !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're using `the_field()` when attempting to append a value to a variable. `the_field()` is used to output the field rather than return it which is why you're running into this issue.

Replace `the_field()` with `get_field()` and it should work.

Comment: You were right, the solution was:                                                          $gallery .= '<h2 class="portfolio-subtitle">' . get_field('subtitle',$post_id) . '</h2>';